# how to set an image using a url from a data set on code.org

Tags: javascript, code.org

i have a program that takes info from a data set about birds and it will show a random bird and its info based on a random number that's generated I have everything down except the image part

I tried using

```
setImageURL("birdInfoImage",birdImage[index]);
```

in a function but an error appeared saying "setImageURL() url parameter value (undefined) is not a string"

Edit: this is for a homework assignment on code.org. The picture should be taken from the data set in the site in the "image of bird" column

```
var birdImage = getColumn("100 Birds of the World", "Image of Bird");
```

then I used bird image in a function to use the URL of the image in the data set and set that URL as the image

```
 onEvent("initiateButton","click",function(){
  var index = getNumber("randomNumberOutput");
  setText("birdInfoName", reducedBirdList[index]);
  setText("birdInfoScientificName", reducedBirdList[index]);
  setText("birdInfoColor", PrimaryColor[index]);
  setText("birdInfoDiet", birdDiet[index]);
  setImageURL("birdInfoImage",birdImage[index]);
```

hope that helped

Comment: You need to show an example of the dataset and a sample of your code.  What does `birdImage` look like?

Comment: @Kinglish sorry the data set is one about birds that shows the name, color, diet of the bird, etc. bird image is a getColumn function that gets the column named "image of bird" which is just a bunch of links to the bird images. I edited the post so  I hope that helps